# Dataframe contains multiple values in 1 column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am pulling data from an API, put it into a dataframe, and it came back like this.

```
name      preferences                                             zip_code
billy     {'email':False, 'print':False, 'charge':False}          12345
sam       {'email':False, 'print':False, 'charge':False}          55555
edward    {'email':False, 'print':False, 'charge':False}          68954
```

How can I produce results that look like this:

```
name      email     print     charge     zip_code
billy     FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      12345
sam       FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      55555
edward    FALSE     FALSE     FALSE      68954
```

While my previous example was fine, I am now getting a new error when I try with a similar column:

> All arrays must be of the same length

Here is what another scenario:

```
    name      phone_numbers                                      zip_code
    billy     [{'phone_number':'1234567890'}]                         12345
    sam       [{'phone_number':'1234567890'},{'phone_number':'2222222222'}]    55555
    edward    [{'phone_number':'4444444444'}]                         68954
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the `preferences` column to dataframe, and `join`:

```
(df.drop('preferences', axis=1)
   .join(pd.DataFrame(df['preferences'].to_dict()).T)
)
```

output:

```
     name  zip_code  email  print  charge
0   billy     12345  False  False   False
1     sam     55555  False  False   False
2  edward     68954  False  False   False
```

Comment: This worked for that particular column, but when I tried on similar columns I got "All Arrays must be of the same length. 

Do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: Can you update your question with an example of a non working case?

Comment: Done, thank you!